# constrOptim throws error "initial parameters not in constrained region" althoug they are within it

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

-I'm running an optimization with `constrOptim()`.

The starting parameter values need to satisfy my constraints. This should be the case, but `constrOptim` throws an error:

> Initial value not in feasible region

What am I getting wrong?

Look at these constraints

```
ci <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,  -1 , -1,  -1,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1)
ui <- matrix(
         c( 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,
            0,  1,  0,  0,  0,
            0,  0,  1,  0,  0,
            0,  0,  0,  1,  0,
            0,  0,  0,  0,  1,
           -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,
            0, -1,  0,  0,  0,
            0,  0, -1,  0,  0,
            0,  0,  0, -1,  0,
            0,  0,  0,  0, -1,
            0,  1,  1,  0,  0,
            0, -1, -1,  0,  0,
            0,  0,  0,  1,  1,
            0,  0,  0, -1, -1), ncol=5, byrow=T)
```

Let's use these initial parameters:

```
par <- c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

...and let's check if they satisfy the constraints, as described in the "details" section of the [documentation of constrOptim](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html). (they seem to satisfy the constraints)

```
ui %*% par - ci >= 0
# TRUE
```

But running `constOptim()` throws the error that the parms are not in the feasible region.

```
constrOptim(theta = par,
        f = function(x) -sum(x),
        ui = ui,
        ci = ci)
# Error: Initial parameters not in feasible region
```

Comment: Is the starting point in the _interior_ of the feasible region, or on the boundary?

Comment: both (either inside or directly at the boundary) according to the documentation of constrOptim.

Comment: According to the docs, the starting point has to be in the interior. Might want to check that.

Comment: Indeed: with `ci <- ci - 1e-6` it works fine. Note: you may need to add `grad=NULL` to the call to `constrOptim`.

Comment: haha, so true. @HongOoi, if you post this as answer, I'll happily credit you.